# Add static reference to thread

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am using **FileSystemWatcher** to monitor some folders and in case of activity on that folders, another **FileSystemWatcher_Created** is called to copy the folder with all files inside.
**These folders are large**, so I am having problems in the form (freezing).

I am using below code to monitor folders:

```
private static void MonitorDirectory1(string path1)
    {
        try
        {
            FileSystemWatcher fileSystemWatcher1 = new FileSystemWatcher();
            fileSystemWatcher1.Path = path1;
            fileSystemWatcher1.Created += FileSystemWatcher_Created1;
            fileSystemWatcher1.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

And below is the code to copy folders and all the contets to a new path:

```
private static void FileSystemWatcher1_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        WatcherChangeTypes wct = e.ChangeType;
        Console.WriteLine("File {0} {1}", e.FullPath, wct.ToString());
        var pathSource = e.FullPath;
        var pathDestination = @"C:\Log";
        foreach (var path1 in Directory.GetDirectories(pathSource, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path.Replace(pathSource, pathDestination));
        foreach (var files in Directory.GetFiles(pathSource, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        File.Copy(files, files.Replace(pathSource, pathDestination), true);
    }
```

My question is: how can I use threads to monitor and trigger another function inside static reference?

Comment: unless this is *sample* code, it wouldn't - `FileSystemWatcher` would get disposed within the method and won't register events

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the *async and await pattern* and `Task.Run` to offload the work to the *threadpool*.

<sub>***Note 1** : Usually you wouldn't use `async void`, or use a task for non IO bound work, however this is an exception.*</sub>

Firstly, `async void` is suited for events, so.. tick

Secondly, Even though the implementation of method has no explicit `async` and it will tie up a *thread*, we can use the *async and await pattern* to run the *task* (most likely in a thread pool thread), using the current syncronization context (if applicable) and you need a continuation back on the main thread, and freeing up the ui... tick

<sub>***Note** 2 : Because we are using the `async void`, if you get 2 events for the same file, you may or likely run into locking and general thread safety issues, you need to be defensive against this*</sub>

```
private static async void FileSystemWatcher1_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
{
 
     await Task.Run(() =>
     {
        WatcherChangeTypes wct = e.ChangeType;
        Console.WriteLine("File {0} {1}", e.FullPath, wct.ToString());
        var pathSource = e.FullPath;
        var pathDestination = @"C:\Log";
        foreach (var path1 in Directory.GetDirectories(pathSource, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path.Replace(pathSource, pathDestination));
        foreach (var files in Directory.GetFiles(pathSource, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        File.Copy(files, files.Replace(pathSource, pathDestination), true);
    });
}
```

<sub>***Note** 3 : This is not intended to be a complete solution, and only a suggestion for using the above technologies, you should research Tasks, and the async await pattern for your own benefit to see how it can help you*</sub>

Comment: Worked like a charm, just added async for each of 20 tasks and now they run smoothly. Thanks a lot.